# Verify number of times request was made

Tags: cypress

Using Cypress Intercept to mock the routes and I want to verify the number of times the route was called.  So far, I've found nothing in the docs for this.  There's mention of `cy.spy` but it only returns 1, every time.  There's a `{times:N}` object for the intercepted route, but it allows the route to match and succeed any number of times.  It doesn't function as a call limit.  This is such a common need that I'm sure I'm just missing something, tired eyes and all.

Spy:

```
cy.intercept({method: 'GET', url:'my-url', middleware:cy.spy().as('myspy')})
```

Times:

```
 cy.intercept({method: 'GET', url:'my-url'}, {times:0})
```

Cypress Feature request: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/16655

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cypress intercept is the spy.

The problem is when to check the call count.

For example, `http://cypress.io/page-data`

```js
it('counts intercepts', () => {

  let requestCounter = 0;
  let responseCounter = 0;

  cy.intercept('page-data/**/*', (req) => {
    requestCounter += 1;                            // count requests
    req.on('response', () => responseCounter += 1 )  // or count responses
  })

  cy.visit('https://www.cypress.io/')

  cy.wait(5000).then(() => {               // arbitrary wait
    expect(requestCounter).to.eq(18)       // since we don't know exactly
    expect(responseCounter).to.eq(18)      // what loads last
  })                                       

})
```

---

The answer given by Jennifer Shehane in the linked feature request shows another way using `<alias>.all`,

```js
it('counts intercepts', () => {

  cy.intercept('page-data/**/*')
    .as('pageData')

  cy.visit('https://www.cypress.io/')

  cy.get('@pageData.all')
    .should('have.length', 18);

})
```

However, it does not consistently pass. About 1 in 5 runs on my machine fail because the cy.get() responds too early.

Ideally you should be able add a timeout, but this currently has no effect.

```js
cy.get('@pageData.all', { timeout: 10000 })  // does not observe the timeout
```

Using `cy.spy()` as a routeHandler allows a timeout to be set on the code that checks the call count.

```js
it('counts intercepts', () => {

  cy.intercept({ url: 'page-data/**/*', middleware: true }, req => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
      res.setDelay(2000)               // artificial delay to force failure
    })
  })

  const spy = cy.spy();
  cy.intercept('page-data/**/*', spy)

  cy.visit('https://www.cypress.io/')

  cy.wrap({}, { timeout: 10000 })     // adjust timeout to suit worst case page load
    .should(() => {
      console.log('testing spy')      // see the retry happening (90+ logs)
      expect(spy).to.be.callCount(18)
    })

})
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this problem to be a rare reason to use a local variable in Cypress:

```js
it('Counts intercepts', () => {

    let count = 0

    cy.intercept('GET','/route', req => {
        count = count+1;
        req.reply({})
    })

    //... your tests
    
    cy.get('body').then( () => {
        expect(count,'Number of times intercepted').to.equal(1) //Assert intercepted only once
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing because we have demo accounts that are not meant to ever reach/call our apis. After doing some research, this is what ended up working for me:

```js
describe('demo accounts', () => {
  beforeEach(function spyOnApiCalls() {
    cy.intercept(/payment-platform/, cy.spy().as('coreApi'))
    cy.intercept(/service-management/, cy.spy().as('mgmtApi'))
  })

  afterEach(function assertApisWereNotCalled() {
    cy.get('@coreApi').its('callCount').should('equal', 0)
    cy.get('@mgmtApi').its('callCount').should('equal', 0)
  })

  it('start test blocks', () => {...})
})
```

Note how we're passing and aliasing instances of the `cy.spy`, then later asserting against them. IMO, this also reads pretty well with the `its('callCount').should('equal', expectedCallCount)`.

Here we have `beforeEach` and `afterEach` blocks because it made sense in my case, but this approach seems pretty flexible and should work in many other scenarios.

Comment: How can you also verify that the call was made 5 times and at all 5 times it returned status 200? Can you do something like that with spy as well? I didn't manage to find my way around it. But that would be also cool to be able to do it :)

Comment: I'm not working with Cypress anymore, so I can't test it myself, but have you tried something like `cy.get('@coreApi').its('statusCode').should('equal', 200)`? I just checked https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept and should have access to `statusCode`.

Answer (score 2):

The following command works.

Note that `cy.get` doesn't work with the leading `@` but it feels more expected to me, so this will work with or without it.

Add this to `/cypress/support/commands.js`

```
Cypress.Commands.add(`verifyCallCount`, (alias, expectedNumberOfCalls) => {
  const resolvedAlias = alias[0] === `@` ? alias.substring(1) : alias

  cy.get(`${resolvedAlias}.all`).then((calls) => {
    cy.wrap(calls.length).should(`equal`, expectedNumberOfCalls)
  })
})
```

Usage:

```
cy.verifyCallCount(`@createLogEntry`, 3)
// Or
cy.verifyCallCount(`createLogEntry`, 3)
```

Comment: This, same as all the mentions of `@aliasName.all` does not work if the call has not been made. So you can't use it to assert that a certain action does *not* cause the call to fire.