# Verify number of Api calls in cypress

Tags: cypress, github-actions, e2e-testing

We are using segment in our application and i need to implement an E2E test in order to verify the number of segment calls, i must be sure that every event will be called only once.
I've been searching for a while, i've found this `command` that verifies the number of api calls:

```
Cypress.Commands.add(`verifyCallCount`, (alias, expectedNumberOfCalls) => {
  const resolvedAlias = alias[0] === `@` ? alias.substring(1) : alias;
  cy.get(`${resolvedAlias}.all`, { timeout: 20000 }).then((calls) => {
    cy.wrap(calls.length).should(`equal`, expectedNumberOfCalls);
  });
});
```

I use this command after waiting for the api call:

```
  cy.wait(`@${eventAlias}`, { timeout: 20000 })
      .then((interception) => {
        return JSON.parse(interception.request.body);
      })
      .then(() => cy.verifyCallCount(eventAlias, 1););
```

Here is also the place where i add my alias for the api call.

```
beforeEach(() => {
 cy.intercept('POST', 'https://api.segment.io/v1', (req) => {
      const body = JSON.parse(req.body);

      if (body.hasOwnProperty('type') && body.type === SampleEvent) {
        req.alias = eventAlias;
      }
    });
  });
 });
```

Using this approach, when i run the test on local environment, it passes without any problem. but the same test fails on github's actions. and this is the error:

```
 AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: `eventAlias.all`, but never found it.
```

I think that the `.get()` command is not being executed after `.wait()`, i tried to change the order of the commands, but it's not helping.

How can i fix this problem in github actions?

Is there any other way to verify the number of api calls in cypress?

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: The `.get()` is being executed, but it is unable to find the call actually being triggered - is there any way for you to verify that the calls are actually occurring on GA?

Comment: it is being called because when i remove `cy.verifyCallCount(eventAlias, 1)`, the test passes on github actions., which means that the calls are occuriring.
i can't figure out why `.get()` can not find it. @agoff

Comment: Can you add the code where you're defining your alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal is to ensure only 1 API call.

You will need the test to wait and see if a 2nd call occurs.

```js
it('accurately test that only one API call happens', () => {

  const numOfRequests = 1

  cy.intercept('**/api/*', cy.spy().as('api-spy'))
  
  cy.visit('/');

  cy.wait(1000)
  
  cy.get('@api-spy').its('callCount').should('equal', numOfRequests)

})
```

I tested with a simple page that deliberately calls twice, with a delay 100ms between calls,

```html
<script>
  fetch('api/1')
  setTimeout(() => fetch('api/2'), 100)  // delayed 2nd fetch we want to test for
</script>
```

Without the hard wait the test gives me a ***false pass***.

---

I also tried inverting the logic, but it still needs a hard wait to test correctly

```js
cy.intercept('**/api/*', cy.spy().as('api-spy'))
  
cy.visit('/');

cy.wait(1000)
  
cy.get('@api-spy').its('callCount')
  .should('not.equal', 0)
  .and('not.equal', 2)                 // false pass without hard wait
})
```

---

#### Counting inside the routeHandler that checks body.type

**2nd alias for call count**

```js
before(() => {
  cy.wrap(0).as('eventCount')
})

beforeEach(() => {
 cy.intercept('POST', 'https://api.segment.io/v1', (req) => {
      const body = JSON.parse(req.body);

      if (body.hasOwnProperty('type') && body.type === SampleEvent) {
        req.alias = eventAlias;
        cy.get('@eventCount').then(count => {
          cy.wrap(count + 1).as('eventCount')
        })
      }
    });
  });
});

it('checks the count', () => {
  cy.visit('/');
  cy.wait(1000)
  cy.get('@eventCount')
    .should('equal', 1)
})
```

**Incrementing a global**

```js
let eventCount = 0;

beforeEach(() => {
 cy.intercept('POST', 'https://api.segment.io/v1', (req) => {
      const body = JSON.parse(req.body);

      if (body.hasOwnProperty('type') && body.type === SampleEvent) {
        req.alias = eventAlias;
        eventCount += 1
      }
    });
  });
});

it('checks the count', () => {
  cy.visit('/');
  cy.wait(1000)
    .then(() => {
      cy.wrap(eventCount)
        .should('equal', 1)
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is, i can't just use `cy.intercept('**/api/*', cy.spy().as('api-spy'))`, because i have similar api calls with different `body.type` and i need to detect the one i need.
is there a way to update your approach based on this? @Mads Brugger

Comment: I suppose you could use a global variable and increment it on each call,  after `req.alias = eventAlias;`. I am wondering if a dynamic alias the way you have used will reset the alias call count each time. Maybe the only option is a second alias to hold the count.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in case of having a global variable to increment, if im gonna have more than one `it()` , is there a way to initialise `eventCount` before each `it()` ? @Mads Brugger

Answer (score 4):

The answer you used from here [Verify number of times request was made](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69754191/16997707) is wrong.

The line `const resolvedAlias = alias[0] === '@' ? alias.substring(1) : alias` removes the initial `@`, but it needs to be kept.

Also the timeout in `cy.get('${resolvedAlias}.all', { timeout: 20000 })` has no effect, it doesn't wait 20 seconds for all calls to happen.

In your test scenario there may be 0, 1, or 2 calls. You want to fail if there is 0 calls or 2 calls, and pass if there is exactly 1 call.

This is enough to fail if there is 0 calls

```js
cy.wait(`@${eventAlias}`, { timeout: 20000 })
```

To fail if there are 2 calls, you must use a hard wait, then verify the call count

```js
cy.wait(`@${eventAlias}`, { timeout: 20_000 })

cy.wait(2_000)                   // wait an interval for any extra call to occur

cy.get(`@${eventAlias}.all`)
  .its('length')
  .should(`equal`, 1);           // if two calls happened in interval, fail here
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, adding a hard wait before `.get()` method didn't work. @A.A.Govil

Answer (score 2):

I notice you mention github actions. I had similar problems when testing an API call in CI, the test runs much slower and cause flakiness.

I suggest mocking the response to get better, more consistent performance from your test.
Ref: [Controlling the response](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Controlling-the-response)

As a bonus, there is no need for any long timeout because your mock replies immediately.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
 cy.intercept('POST', 'https://api.segment.io/v1', (req) => {
      const body = JSON.parse(req.body);

      if (body.hasOwnProperty('type') && body.type === SampleEvent) {
        req.alias = eventAlias;

        // here send mock response without any network delay
        req.reply({
          headers: {
            Set-Cookie: 'newUserName=Peter Pan;'
          },
          statusCode: 201,
          body: {
            name: 'Peter Pan'
          }
        })
      }
    });
  });
})

it('tests there is only a single POST from app', () => {

  cy.wait(`@${eventAlias}`)
  cy.wait(100)  
  cy.get(`@${eventAlias}.all`).then((calls) => {
    cy.wrap(calls.length).should(`equal`, 1);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but again i'm receiving error for`cy.get(@${eventAlias}.all)`. it says there is not registered alias. @Genevieve OR

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get all of the alias calls, you will need to use `@` to signify the alias. So the custom command will need to be updated.

```
Cypress.Commands.add(`verifyCallCount`, (registeredAlias, expectedNumberOfCalls) => {
  if(alias[0] !== '@') {
   throw new Error ('alias does not start with '@')
  }
  cy.get(`${registeredAlias}.all`, { timeout: 20000 }).then((calls) => {
    cy.wrap(calls.length).should(`equal`, expectedNumberOfCalls);
  });
});
```

Usage

```
cy.intercept('call').as('call')
// some action to trigger call
cy.wait('@call')
// some other actions
cy.verifyCallCount('@call')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've added `@` to signify the alias, but it didn't work. 
@jjhelguero

Comment: After adding `@`, the new error says `CypressError: cy.get() could not find a registered alias for: @alias.` @jjhelguero

Comment: Well, `alias` will be whatever your alias text is set for the intercept.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any other way to verify the number of api calls in cypress?

This is a concise way to count the api calls and wait for them to finish.

You can pass a `cy.spy()` in as a "response" and you can use that to count the number of times the intercept was hit.

Using `.should()` in the Cypress assertion will wait until the expected number of requests to come back.

```js
it('test', () => {
  const numOfRequests = 5;
  cy.intercept('https://api.segment.io/v1', cy.spy().as('api-spy'));

  // Do something to trigger 5 requests

  cy.get('@api-spy').its('callCount').should('equal', numOfRequests);
});
```

If there are a sequence of different endpoints you are waiting for such as `/v1/login` followed by a `/v1/getData` etc, the URL in the `cy.intercept` may need to use a wildcard.

For example:

```js
cy.intercept('https://api.segment.io/v1/**')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in your solution, can i use `api-spy` to wait for the api call? @DJSDev

Comment: @Mona The cool thing is, you don't actually have to call `cy.wait()` to have Cypress wait. This is because Cypress will wait on the assertion `.should('equal', numOfRequests);` to pass. You can increase the timeout with `cy.get('@api-spy', {timeout: 10000})` if you need more time for the api calls..

Comment: It would be cool if it worked, but sadly it doesn't - the `.should()` is not ensuring no more than 1 call, which is what @Mona is asking for.